# Media Queries Not Being Triggered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am creating a responsive site right now but unfortunately my media queries are not being triggered. I have supplied the code, completely copied and pasted as-is from my document that I am using, below.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong that is preventing my media queries from being called?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- USE THIS ONE WHEN WP GOES <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>!-->
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

    <!-- Icon !-->
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />

    <!--<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" /> !-->
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<!-- USE THIS ONE WHEN WP GOES <body <?php body_class(); ?>> !-->
<body>

<!-- header !-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- navigation -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" width="300" height="131" alt="Logo"/></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Engagement</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Diamonds</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Jewelry</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Watches</a>
                </li>
                <li><hr /></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">News & Events</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                <li><hr /></li>
                <li> insert social media icons here </li>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
<!-- end header !-->


        <!-- content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
            <div class="page-content inset">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis consectetur lobortis metus, eu lacinia lorem mollis eu. Etiam faucibus in diam sed rhoncus. Aliquam a aliquam ante, in sollicitudin est. Aenean vehicula viverra commodo. Nullam malesuada metus odio, id luctus lorem dapibus vel. Proin sit amet leo vel diam pharetra mattis eu sed ante. Proin ut metus tellus. Pellentesque lorem justo, mollis ut auctor vel, aliquam vel tortor. Cras ut lectus mauris. Aenean porta at dolor id imperdiet. Donec neque velit, commodo id suscipit et, ultricies et orci. Nullam ante mauris, congue eget laoreet eget, rhoncus vitae enim.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="well">Cras ut lectus mauris. Aenean porta at dolor id imperdiet. Donec neque velit, commodo id suscipit et, ultricies et orci. Nullam ante mauris, congue eget laoreet eget, rhoncus vitae enim.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="well">Cras ut lectus mauris. Aenean porta at dolor id imperdiet. Donec neque velit, commodo id suscipit et, ultricies et orci. Nullam ante mauris, congue eget laoreet eget, rhoncus vitae enim.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p class="well">Cras ut lectus mauris. Aenean porta at dolor id imperdiet. Donec neque velit, commodo id suscipit et, ultricies et orci. Nullam ante mauris, congue eget laoreet eget, rhoncus vitae enim.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p class="well">Cras ut lectus mauris. Aenean porta at dolor id imperdiet. Donec neque velit, commodo id suscipit et, ultricies et orci. Nullam ante mauris, congue eget laoreet eget, rhoncus vitae enim.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p class="well">Cras ut lectus mauris. Aenean porta at dolor id imperdiet. Donec neque velit, commodo id suscipit et, ultricies et orci. Nullam ante mauris, congue eget laoreet eget, rhoncus vitae enim.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Fonts */
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans');

/* Global */
@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 340px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.inset {
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Navigation */
#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -340px;
    left: 340px;
    width: 340px;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 340px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    line-height: 40px;
    text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    color: #999999;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 131px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}



/* Responsive Fixes */

@media screen (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1279px {
}

@media screen (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
}

@media screen (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        margin-left: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 230px;
    }

    #sidebar-nav {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .inset {
        padding: 15px;
    }
}

@media screen (max-width: 480px) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need a `and` between screen and the max/min width. Also your first media query is missing an ending bracket `(max-width: 1279px` see

http://jsfiddle.net/QM54b

```
@media screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    body {background: green;}
}
```

Because of the missing bracket, the rest of the media query will not be triggered

Comment: Oh my gosh, I knew it was something ridiculous like that. Thank you!